# How to implement fullcalendar tooltip

Tags: fullcalendar, tooltip

I am trying to add tooltip to fullcalendar. I use Angular 2 module (ap-angular2-fullcalendar). The tooltip needs to be created programmatically so the tooltip content match the event content (example: description).

I tried to use **qtip** and **material MatToolTip** libraries but without success (I managed to add tooltip to DOM but it is not working).

Comment: It's going to be fairly hard for folks to help without seeing your work. Could you add a [mcve] into your question?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender) e.g.

```
      eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
        $el.popover({
          title: eventObj.title,
          content: eventObj.description,
          trigger: 'hover',
          placement: 'top',
          container: 'body'
        });
      },
```

See a working example [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo) - note this example relies on Bootstrap and Popper.js

You can also use Bootstrap tooltip instead of the popover e.g.

```
      eventRender: function(event, element) {
        $(element).tooltip({title: event.tooltip,
                  container: 'body',
                  delay: { "show": 500, "hide": 300 }
        });
      },
```

Comment: Hi, 
It doesn't seem to work

caught TypeError: element.popover is not a function .                                                                                               eventRender: (event, element) => {
      element.popover({
        title: event.title,
        content: event.description,
        trigger: 'hover',
        placement: 'top',
        container: 'body'
      });
      }

Comment: Hi @Adam007, popover comes with Bootstrap and Popover.js, so you need to make sure that you are loading the Bootstrap and Popover libraries properly. If you view source on the working example, I linked to, you will see how to include them both. Also make sure you have them in the right order. view-source:https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo

Comment: Hi Trojan, the problem is that I don't want to include bootstrap library. I use angular framework and it works better without it. Tnx a lot anyway